# Hitting URL empty the Requested Data?

Tags: magento-1.9

http://localhost/testsetup/index.php/inquiry/index/index

```
echo "<pre>"; print_r($data); die;

Array
(
    [qty] => 1
    [product] => 486
)
```

Case 1.
When i press ctrl+f5 (reload the inquiry page) , Array data is there.
This is ok for me.

```
Array
(
    [qty] => 1
    [product] => 486
)
```

case 2.
Array data is empty. When i hit the URL of page.

```
 Array
    (

    )
```

How to solve case 2 so that array data is not empty when i hit the URL.

Answer (score 0):

If Form Data is posted on URL and If you refresh the Page, Form Data will be lost.

To keep the form data, you need to save in Session like below:

```
Mage::getSingleton(‘core/session’)->setFormData($data);
$data = Mage::getSingleton(‘core/session’)->getFormData();
```

After completing your all work, You can remove the unset the session like below:

```
Mage::getSingleton(‘core/session’)->unsFormData();
```

Comment: it is not working : Mage::getSingleton(‘core/session’)->setFormData($data);
$data = Mage::getSingleton(‘core/session’)->getFormData();

Comment: What error you are getting ? can you try with one simple varible first

Comment: same empty array, after using core/session

Comment: Which class your controller extending ?

Comment: class Custom_Inquiry_IndexController extends Mage_Core_Controller_Front_Action

Comment: Try `setCustomData` and `getCustomData` to set values or something else unique